# INVALID JOBEXECUTION, ID 0 NOT FOUND

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Batch Job. When I try to host batch job in Tomcat, I am getting below exception:

- org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.NoSuchObjectException: 
  Invalid JobExecution, ID 15584 not found.    at
  org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.updateJobExecution(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:197)

Whereas If I try to execute batch job as Standalone, It is working and updated in Database Batch tables.

It may be minor issue but unable to figure it out. I searched online. But unable to get the solution for this.

Config files:

applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.sample.feed" />

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/data-source-context.xml" />

<bean id="simpleStep"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleStepFactoryBean"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobExplorer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="lobHandler" ref="lobHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="lobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler" />

<bean id="jobParameterIncrementer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer" />

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <!-- <property name="taskExecutor" ref="jobLauncherTaskExecutor" /> -->
</bean>

<batch:job id="SAMPLEAppFeedLoader" job-repository="jobRepository"
    incrementer="jobParameterIncrementer" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
    <batch:step id="FeedDBProcessing" parent="simpleStep">      
        <!-- <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor"> -->
        <batch:tasklet>
            <!-- throttle-limit="10"> -->
            <chunk reader="SAMPLEAppReader" writer="DBBatchWriter"
                processor="SAMPLEAppProcessor" commit-interval="1">
            </chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="SAMPLEAppLoader" class="com.sample.feed.model.SAMPLEAppLoader" />

<bean id="itemReader" class="com.sample.feed.reader.SynchronisedReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="delegate" ref="SAMPLEAppReader" />
</bean>


<bean id="SAMPLEAppReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="saveState" value="false" />

    <property name="sql">

        <value> <![CDATA[ select e.MONT_DATA_VAL_ID, e.SUBR_NBR, e.RES_BLOB.getClobVal() 
            clobvalue from MON_DATA_VAL e where e.MONT_DATA_VAL_ID >= 588369 AND e.MONT_DATA_VAL_ID 
            <= 588389]]>
        </value>

    </property>
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.sample.feed.mapper.SAMPLEAppMapper" />
    </property>
    <property name="verifyCursorPosition">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="SAMPLEAppProcessor" class="com.sample.feed.processor.SAMPLEAppProcessor">
    <property name="filePath" value="D:\\input\\SAMPLEapp\\" />
</bean>

<bean id="SAMPLEAppWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[
        update MON_DATA_VAL set path = :filePathValue where MONT_DATA_VAL_ID = :mont_data_val_id  
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>

    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="DBBatchWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="assertUpdates" value="true" />
    <property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter">
        <bean class="com.sample.feed.mapper.PSSetter" />
    </property>
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
        <![CDATA[
        update MON_DATA_VAL set path = ? where MONT_DATA_VAL_ID = ?
        ]]>
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="SAMPLEFeedWriter" class="com.sample.feed.writer.SAMPLEAPPWriter">
    <property name="SAMPLEMessageDao" ref="SAMPLEMessageDao" />
</bean>

<bean id="SAMPLEMessageDao" class="com.sample.feed.daoImpl.SAMPLEMessageDaoImpl">
    <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
    <property name="SAMPLEUpdateQuery"
        value="update MON_DATA_VAL set path = ? where MONT_DATA_VAL_ID = ?" />
    <property name="SAMPLEAppLoader" ref="SAMPLEAppLoader" />
</bean>
```

data-source-context.xml:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="BATCH_" />
    <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT" />
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="URL" value="${batch.jdbc.url}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}"></property>
    <property name="user" value="${batch.jdbc.user}"></property>
</bean>



<bean id="namedJdbcTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

note: It may be cause of multithreading?. Here I removed multithreading and checked too. Still the exception persists.

Comment: Job Parameters:  run.id(long)=4

Comment: You said when you run your job as a standalone app it works, and when your run it from tomcat it fails. Correct? Is your tomcat pointing to the correct data source?

Comment: Correct. But the Issue resolved since I pointed to different class package(default domain) in jmx-context.xml                                                                                                                              <context:mbean-export default-domain="com.export.feed" server="mbeanServer" /><int-jmx:mbean-export id="integrationMBeanExporter" default-domain="com.export.feed" server="mbeanServer" />

Comment: ok, glad you fixed your issue.